# Non-reentrant non-blocking semaphore in Java

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore, nonblocking

I need a semaphore with the following features:

1. it should be non-blocking, i.e. if the thread cannot get the permit
   it should go further without waiting
2. it should be nonreentrant, i.e. if the same thread enters the
   guarded piece of code twice it should take away two permits instead of
   one

I have written the following code:

```
public class SimpleSemaphore
{

    private int permits;

    private AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    SimpleSemaphore(int permits)
    {
        this.permits = permits;
    }

    boolean acquire()
    {

        if (counter.incrementAndGet() < permits)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            counter.decrementAndGet();
            return false;
        }

    }

    void release()
    {
        counter.decrementAndGet();

    }
}
```

Another option is this Semaphore:

```
public class EasySemaphore
{

    private int permits;

    private AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    EasySemaphore(int permits)
    {
        this.permits = permits;
    }

    boolean acquire()
    {
        long index = counter.get();

        if (index < permits)
        {
            if (counter.compareAndSet(index, index + 1))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    void release()
    {
        counter.decrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

Are the both implementations thread-safe and correct?
Which one is better?
How would you go about this task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Doesn't [`java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) already do all that?

It has a `tryAcquire` for non-blocking acquire, and it maintains a simple count of remaining permits (of which the same thread could take out more than one).

Comment: Really, tryAcquire method is what I need, thanks! But what about reentrance of java.util.concurrent.Semaphore? I cannot find any evidence in docs that one thread may take out many permits.

Comment: It says in the docs that there is no tracking of ownership, just a simple counter, and that the semaphore can be released from a different thread than the one that acquired it. I think your requirement follows from this.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the second one is better as the counter will never be greater thathan 0 (and its slightly more efficient)

I would use a loop otherwise you can have the method fail when there is still permits left.

```
public class EasySemaphore {
    private final AtomicInteger counter;

    EasySemaphore(int permits) {
        counter = new AtomicInteger(permits);
    }

    boolean acquire() {
        // highly unlikely to loop more than once.
        while(true) {
            int count = counter.get();
            if (count <= 0) return false;
            if (counter.compareAndSet(count, count -1)) 
                return true;
        }
    }

    void release() {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```